# Why is Memory Usage section disabled in performance profiler?

Tags: c#, memory, visual-studio-2017, profiler

I would like to run Memory Usage session or Object Allocation (preferable both) but I have only available types CPU Usage and GPU Usage. VS does not show any hint while given section is disabled.

I tried out several other projects I wrote and one after another all have just those two sections.

*I run 64-bit Windows 10.*

Answer (score 18):

It's possible that the current tool selection prevents you from selecting what you want.

For example, here's what I see:

[image: CPU usage and Database selected]

I can't select the `Memory Usage` tool unless I deselect both the `CPU Usage` and `Database` tools:

[image: Memory Usage selected]

Answer (score 3):

In my case, Memory Usage was disabled because of project's framework version. It was set to 3.5. When I changed it to newest (on my computer 4.7.2), Memory Usage functionality starts working.
After profiling, I will change framework version back to 3.5, due to our product compatibility.

Framework version settings is in: Project / Properties / Application / Target Framework

Answer (score 2):

If **.NET Object Allocation Tool** option is disabled/not applicable when trying to start profiler for a Web project, ensure that **Start Action** is not set to "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application".

This solution worked for me:

1. Switch **Project Properties -> Web -> **Start Action**** to "**Current Page**"
2. Save the project
3. Close Diagnostic tools window and open a new one (**ALT+F2**)

The option **.NET Object Allocation Tool** should be moved from section "Not Applicable Tools" to "Available Tools"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In may case, changing the **Analysis Target** to **Startup Project** instead of **Running Process** and **Executable** fixed the issue (Project targets .NET 4.8)