# .NET Object Allocation Tracking not enabled in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, memory-profiling

I am trying to profile the .NET object Allocation in the profiling tools in Visual Studio.

Unfortunately, the option ":NET Object Allocation Tracking" is not enabled for my project.

My project is a .NET 7 application.

Thanks for you help

Comment: I have the same problem but with a .net 4.6.2 web api application. I can select most options but not the object allocation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Memory Usage section disabled in performance profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571930/why-is-memory-usage-section-disabled-in-performance-profiler)

Comment: No. not for me.

Answer (score 2):

I seems that ".NET Object Allocation Tracking" is mutually exclusive with all other options. Uncheck all of the others tools and it should be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I openned the Performance profiler, the **Memory Usage** was preselected. If that's your case deselect it and **the .Net Object Allocation Tracking** will be enabled

Comment: nope this did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and after few hours of investigation it turned out that IISExpress is causing the problem.

It worked like a charm after switching to kestrel.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35656729)